# "Failed to open video device /dev/video0 no such file or directory" with normal working usb camera in motion

Tags: pi-2, camera, webcam, motion

I have a normal usb 2.0 cam. Connecting it to my pc, it works perfectly. It is not working with my raspberry pi (2). I had installed motion and it had worked good before 2/3 weeks when I tried it but now, it says

> [1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
>
> [1] Failed to open video device /dev/video0: No such file or directory

When I run:

`sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`
It gives me:

```
ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted
```

I searched up much but did not find a solution. When I run:

```
vcgencmd get_camera
```

I get:

```
supported=1, detected=0
```

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to RPi board Alok. Did you checked https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1532217 ?

Comment: I think that is for the raspberry pi camera module. I am using a normal usb camera...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Solved!!

What I did was:

1) Removed Motion from Raspberry Pi using

`sudo apt-get --purge remove motion`

2) Disabled Raspberry Pi Camera in `raspi-config` and rebooted the Pi

3) Installed fswebcam using

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```

4) Tried capturing a photo with it using

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner image3.jpg
```

5) It worked!! Then Installed Motion and tried streaming it and that also worked!!

This is the solution...

Comment: I am stuck at your point 4. When I enter that command I get a no such file or directory error for /dev/video0. I am running on a raspberry pi zero with raspbian. Running "sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2" does not output anything

Comment: @JRsz Did u try reinstalling motion? Starting from the first step? Make sure you reboot your Pi before installing it again. It worked for me! I was stuck at "no such file or directory" for a couple of weeks! This did work for me... Try reinstalling Raspbian if nothing works