# Raspberry pi camera not showing up on a raspberry pi zero

Tags: raspbian, camera, pi-zero, fswebcam

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero with the latest Raspbian operating system (2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch-lite.img). Attached I have a raspberry pi camera that is not working as it is supposed to be. My setup looks like the image at the bottom of this question.

The issue is that I do not see this device ind the `dev` directory. I would expect to find something like `/dev/video0` but that does not appear. I have tried several instructions. I tried [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45680/failed-to-open-video-device-dev-video0-no-such-file-or-directory-with-normal/46181#comment135584_46181) question on this site but that solution did not work for me. I get this output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ fswebcam -r 640x480 --no-banner image3.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
stat: No such file or directory
```

I have enabled the camera in `sudo raspi-config` and restartet several times.

I have executed the command `sudo modprobe bcm2835_v4l2` but that did not generate any output whatsoever.

I have executed `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade` to have all the latest packages installed.

Both items are new. I bought them two weeks ago. To be even more precise [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0748MPQT4) is the Raspberry Pi kit and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0748KF97S) is the camera.

I am running out of ideas on what else to try. Any help is highly appreciated. My own research on this topic did not help me so far.

**UPDATE:**

Running the command from the first comment produces this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o cam.jpg
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

I think I installed it correctly, as shown in the image below. The two modules on the side do light up so they should be powered.

[image: My camera setup]

Comment: Have you tried the basic installation instructions? Before testing additional software just use `raspistill -o cam.jpg` to test. I don't know why you would run `sudo modprobe bcm2835_v4l2` unless that is part of the fswebcam install?

Comment: See updated question. I did run modprobe because that was one of the suggested solutions I found during my research. However, that did not work for me

Comment: From troubleshooting basics .."Is the Camera Module connector, between the smaller black Camera Module itself and the PCB, firmly attached? Sometimes this connection can come loose during transit or when putting the Camera Module in a case. Using a fingernail, flip up the connector on the PCB, then reconnect it with gentle pressure. It engages with a very slight click. Don't force it; if it doesn't engage, it's probably slightly misaligned."

Comment: Error : ENOMEM. The Camera Module is not starting up. Check all connections again.

Comment: That actually fixed the issue. I attached the modules to the other side and switched the screws :) If you want you can put this up as an answer and I will accept it of course because it fixed my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: I thank you for solving my problem! After several days :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the troubleshooting section on the [Pi Site for the Camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md)

> Error : ENOMEM. The Camera Module is not starting up. Check all
>   connections again

From troubleshooting basics ..

> "Is the Camera Module connector, between the smaller black Camera
>   Module itself and the PCB, firmly attached? Sometimes this connection
>   can come loose during transit or when putting the Camera Module in a
>   case. Using a fingernail, flip up the connector on the PCB, then
>   reconnect it with gentle pressure. It engages with a very slight
>   click. Don't force it; if it doesn't engage, it's probably slightly
>   misaligned."

Answer (score 3):

Probably a bit late, but i had the same issue and it was impossible to find information, maybe this i'll help someone.
My Camera is almost exactly like the one in the photo, and it doesn't have a "sunny" connector.
What fixed it for me was just unscrewing it completely, pressing lightly on the sides of the sensor module, and reattaching everything, except with the LED modules on the front, instead of on the back.